# Is LLVM GEP safe if not know the size of an array?

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to use GEP to get a pointer of i32 from an array.

But the problem is: I don't know the size of the array.

The IR document on llvm.org said GEP just adds the offsets to the base address with silently-wrapping two’s complement arithmetic.

So, I want to ask for some advice.
Is it safe like this:

```
%v1 = alloca i32
store i32 5, i32* %v1
%6 = load i32* %v1
%7 = bitcast i32* %v0 to [1 x i32]*
%8 = getelementptr [1 x i32]* %7, i32 0, i32 %6
%9 = load i32* %8
store i32 %9, i32* %v0
```

Type of %v0 is i32*, and I know %v0 is pointing to an array in mem, but the size is 9, not 1.
Then I "GEP" from %7 which I treat it as a [1 x i32]*, not [9 x i32]* , but the "offset" is 5(%6).

So, is there any problem? Not safe, or just not good but basically OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the entire code you wrote is equivalent to:

```
%x = getelementptr i32* %v0, i32 5
%y = load i32* %x
store i32* %y, %v0
```

There's no reason to bitcast the pointer to `[1 x i32]*`, just use it as-is.

Regarding your question - using a gep to get the pointer is always safe (in the sense that it's well-defined and will never crash), however there's nothing stopping it from evaluating to a pointer beyond the bounds of the array; and in such a case, accessing the memory (as you do in the subsequent `load` instruction) is undefined.

Also, this link might be of interest: http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#what-happens-if-an-array-index-is-out-of-bounds

Comment: thank you for answer. So you mean if I am sure the index is not out of the bound, I would get the ptr or element I want,right?

Comment: If the index is in bounds, then loading it would result in the 5th item in the array.